# Turing machine, tape without blanks, does it halt or no?

Tags: turing-machines, logic

[image]

So I'm lost on this one. We're given a turing machine and an initial tape. Tape is infinitely long in both ways, but all the blanks are taken out. The head is the leftmost nonblank. So the question is: *If the Turing machine
halts on this input, then give the output sequence; if it does not halt, then answer “does not halt” and why.*

Following the turing machine it seems to halt after q1 since  is the only operation.

Edit: and, if a state has only one operation such as  does that mean it automatically should halt?

Comment: If all the blanks are taken out, how can there be a leftmost nonblank?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's what the excercise said. To be exact: "The arrow indicates the initial position of the read/write head: the leftmost nonblank symbol. If the Turing machine halts on this input, then give the output sequence; if it does not halt, then answer “does not halt”. In either case, stating your answer is sufficient; you do not have to justify your answer"

Comment: You’d probably better explain the notation they’re using; it doesn’t make sense to me. Everyone makes up their own Turing machine notation, there’s no standard.

Comment: so the "intial tape" could be 0 | _ | 1 | _ | _ | 1 .. etc. You don't know because they took the blanks out. 

The turing machine: <current state>, <written state>, <move R/L>. The box is a blank.

For that matter, it does not make sense to me either. I tried to search for more explanation but it as you said, everyone has a different notation

Comment: I’m sorry but this seems like an unanswerable question to me. The machine definition doesn’t make sense without a notation definition. The stuff about the blanks being taken out doesn’t make much sense. If you were given this for a course, I’d go back to the instructor and ask them to clarify it.

Comment: In class you must have been given semantics for Turing machines. Unfortunately you have not divulged this information with us. Given the semantics, you should be able to trace out the execution – the point of Turing machines is that they operate in a very simple fashion.

Comment: It seems that you're saying that initial tape does have blanks, but the TM cannot detect these blank symbols. If that's the case, what does TM read the blank symbols as? 0s? 1s? If it's unspecified, then to answer the question you should assume that they could be read as either 0s or 1s. Proving that a given TM halts would involve ruling out that no matter what the TM reads a blank symbol's value as, we will halt.